# Getting NoneType Error on For Loop on Product.Product in OpenERP

Tags: python, odoo

I am working on a custom module for OpenERP 7 (Odoo) and I am struggling to get my function to run. My goal is to create a field called real inventory count, which pulls from the preexisting qty_available and outgoing_qty columns and gives me the difference. I have tried quite a few attempts at this problem, and this code is the latest:

> from openerp.osv import fields, osv
>
> class real_inventory_counter(osv.osv):
>       _inherit = "product.product"
>
> ```
> def real_inventory_count(self, cr, uid, arg, ids, field_name, context=None):
>     result = []
>     for item in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
>         result[item.id] = item.qty_available - item.outgoing_qty
>     return result
>
> _columns = {
>   'real_inventory_count': fields.function(real_inventory_count, type='float', string='Real Inventory Count'),
> }
> ```

Regardless of what I do, I seem to get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'qty_available'

I believe what I want is to return when this method is called is an array of the values. It seems that self.browse is not returning the right type, but I'm not sure. What is causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function definition is wrong in terms of order of arguments. It should be as follow:

```
def real_inventory_count(self, cr, uid, ids, arg, field_name, context=None):
```

Change it like this and it will work.

Comment: This was the correct solution. I copied the arguments from another module written by someone else and obviously they were wrong.